# Explanation of word use in a exam for Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

My exam says do the following on a basic image carousel.

```
the images should wrap around when the user gets to the end of the list
```

Anyone know what they mean ??

Comment: What about when you arrive at last index, the next one should be the first index

Comment: Ahhh,, make sense Hossein :) Thanks buddy

Comment: You're welcome, I didn't sure and delete my answer now it is undeleted ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Means when you arrive at last index, next index must be first:

```
if(index === last_index)
    index = 0;
```

Comment: == not = inside the if.

Comment: Thanks bro, my mistake :)